# How do I can use machine language without using the assembler and operating system?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

How do I can use machine language without using the assembler and operating system?

How do I can enter 0 and 1 directly? I know that this is silly but I want only to know how does it work and can I write program in machine language without using the assembler and operating system and install any additional tools in operating system?

Can I enter 0 and 1 separately by my keyboard? without using the operating system? In fact, programming, from scratch!

Comment: Thank you. But I say "Programming at the lowest level". In the past was not  operating system.So, programmers did not use character for coding.they used click and click( 0 and 1).

Comment: Feel free to write a bootsector that uses BIOS interrupts to read 0s and 1s from the keyboard, stores the bits in RAM and then jumps to that memory location. How you'd actually do that is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Back in the day computers often had a front panel with switches for manually entering bootstrapping code in binary. For obvious reasons modern users wouldn't put up with this and so such interfaces have been abandoned, however it shouldn't be too hard to dig up an old `PDP-11` minicomputer or the like. Or perhaps an `Altair 8800` microcomputer or one of its competitors, though that would set you back a bit. Similarly manually poking a punch card isn't too hard for a system capable of booting that way, just awfully tedious.

Comment: To be able to "enter it on your keyboard" already implies there's software running that can read the keyboard. So it seems what you're asking is a little bit of a contradiction. :p The mechanism for "programming at the lowest level" depends upon your hardware setup.  Your PC hardware is not designed to make it easy to do this. Perhaps the closest you'd get is to reprogram the BIOS flash on your PC with whatever code you created with some kind of binary editor. But it seems that's not exactly what you're after? Unclear...

Comment: To recap: Buy yourself [one of these things](http://altairclone.com).

Answer (score 0):

### Serious part

As pointed out in the comments you cannot load a program into modern computer memory by messing up with switches anymore, it must be in some form of media, in large sense, so that the firmware can load and execute it.

One may program a firmware in a ROM (or similar) with a programmer, this is as close as possible as writing zeros and ones into a computer memory. Note that usually machine code is written in hex rather than binary.

Inside a modern OS you can write machine code with any hex editor, the problem is that program binaries does not contains executable code only. They also contain headers and a lot of "meta" (let's call them this way) data. So you would have to construct a valid structure with all headers, sections and etc.
This is not impossible, it all boils down to some basic math and a good reference, it is just that it is very tedious.

### Game part

As a game, If you want to feel the old thrill of writing programs in binary code you can follow the suggestion of Michael and use a boot program that let you write numbers into memory.

I wrote you one for IA32 (likely your architecture), you have to use NASM to assemble it and write the 512 byte output file to any bootable media (Google will help you). Then restart your computer.

Here some limitations (features?)

- You can only use <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>, every thing else is ignored.
- You cannot correct mistakes or overwrite previous written machine code.
- As soon as 8 bit are entered a byte is written in memory.
- Bytes are written one after the other in the order they are collected.
- You cannot write more then 3,5KiB of data if you need more you have to first write a new program for writing into memory and then use it.
- If you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> the program will execute the machine code you entered.
- If you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> before you have completed a byte, the bits inserted are discarded.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f87jb.gif) me inserting machine code for a program that write *Hi* on the screen.

Here is the code

```
BITS 16
jmp 07c0h:WORD __START__

__START__:
  mov ax, cs
  mov ss, ax
  xor sp, sp
  push cs
  pop ds
  push 0b800h
  pop es



  mov di, 200h  ;Write binary code from 7c0h:200h to 7c0h:ffffh, i.e. 3,5KiB 


.screen_input:  
  mov ax, 03h
  int 10h
  xor si, si

.byte_input:
  mov cx, 0800h

.bit_input:
  xor ah, ah
  int 16h

  cmp al, 0dh
  je .jump

  cmp al, '0'
  jb .bit_input

  cmp al, '1'
  ja .bit_input

  mov ah, 0ch
  mov WORD [es:si], ax
  add si, 02h

  shr al, 1
  rcl cl, 1

  dec ch
  jnz .bit_input

  mov BYTE [di], cl
  inc di

  add si, 90h
  cmp si, 0fa0h
  jae .screen_input

jmp .byte_input

.jump:
  jmp 7c0h:200h

  TIMES 505-($-__START__) db 0
  dw 0aa55h
```